# Concurrent Reading and writing for lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am using lucene 4.5 version.

I am currently reading data from Oracle DB and index all the data into lucene. For now, I need to update the index folder incrementally after ten minutes. So, in that case if I open for writing, my segments files get deleted. So I am not able to do searching from lucene. I tried to see if we can read and write simultaneously.  But I am not able to find any solution for this.

Can anybody suggest some ideas for this?. We are reading less data during incremental. So the data will get indexed very soon. But i cannot down time the searching every ten minutes.
 Sorry if i had repeated the same question.**But i find all the answers for lucene 3.6 and does not suit for me in lucene 4.5 version.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also open the `IndexWriter` for [appending](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.html#CREATE_OR_APPEND)

```
IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(LUCENE_VERSION, analyzer);
iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, iwc);
```

You readers should not be affected by this, they can continue to search. After updating the index, you should reopen you readers, so they can search the updated data.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

1. Create the initial index.
2. After ten minutes, create another index with updated data.
3. Switch the readers to use the updated index when done with 2.
4. Delete the (now outdated) index.
5. See 2.

This suggestion is completely agnostic to any Lucene version.